# Find the number of swaps that has taken place. New Year Chaos. Hackerrank

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I am trying to solve the [following Hackerrank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays).

[image: pixel raster of Hackerrank's problem statement]

I have written the code for the problem. However, it runs for some of the test cases while for others it doesn't. It shows the message : "Your code did not execute within the time limits"

I know that bubble sort is not required for the problem. However, I have seen many people doing it using bubble sort.

I want to do the problem by employing bubble sort. Please tell me what changes do I need to make in the code in order to do so. Thanks for helping.

```
int N = 0 ,I = 0;
        int flag = 0;

        int n = q.length;  
        int temp = 0; 
        int noOfSwaps = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < q.length ; i++)
        {
            N = q[i];
            I = i;
            if((N-I)>3)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Too chaotic");
        }
        else if(flag == 0)
        {
            //System.out.println("Find Exchanges");      

         for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
                 for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                          if(q[j-1] > q[j]){  
                                 //swap elements  
                                 temp = q[j-1];  
                                 q[j-1] = q[j];  
                                 q[j] = temp;  

                                 noOfSwaps++;
                         }  

                 }  
         } 

         System.out.println(noOfSwaps);

        }
```

Comment: "it runs for some of the test cases while for others it doesn't" - Are you getting TLE or WA?

Comment: Right idea but as mentioned above, it's not clear what you're asking. Does the code work? Either way, the algorithm [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220263/171065) might help.

Comment: @vnp It displayed the following message for some of the test cases : Your code did not execute within the time limits

Comment: @ggorlen It displayed the following message for some of the test cases : " Your code did not execute within the time limits"

Comment: Good. Time Limit Exceeded makes the question on topic (Wrong Answer would disqualify it immediately).

Answer (score 2):

### Time limit improvements

- You don't need to implement a full bubble sort (as the maximum distance is 2 bribes!)
- You can skip if a person is in the correct position if you know the processed part is correct.
- You don't need to process the list twice, you only need to check if the person you are checking is within the maximum swap distance.

I commented my algorithm below; it is basically a bubble sort, only with a limit on how far the inner loop goes.

```
public class Solution {

    static final int MAX_SWAPS = 2;

    // Complete the minimumBribes function below.
    static void minimumBribes(int[] q) {
           int bribes = 0;

           int n=q.length;

           //we process from right to left
           for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
           { 
               int pos = i+1;
               int s;

               //if we are correct, we can proceed LEFT, 
               //we know the right tail is correctly sorted
               //so after this step, the tail is 1 longer ans STILL correctly sorted
               if (q[i] == pos) continue;

               //try swap our position with previous positions, look MAX_SWAPS left.

               //for example:   1 5 2 4 3

               //if we are investigating position 5 (currently number 3)
               //we start swapping the items at position 3 and 4 if number 5 is at position 3.

               //if number 5 was not at position 3, 
               //we try to find it at position 4
               //if number 5 was also not at position 4, we are too chaotic, as you 
               //cannot bribe yourself more than MAX_SWAPS to the left.
               //so we are TOO CHAOTIC!

               //for example:   1 2 5 4 3

               //if number 5 is in position 5, we can skip it
               //(it is not)
               //if number 5 is at position 3
               //we swap the numbers 5 and 4 (at position 3 and 4) and have 1 bribe (bribes++)
               //situation becomes: 1 2 4 5 3
               //if now number 5 is at position 4, we have bribed again (bribes++)
               //situation becomes: 1 2 4 3 5

               //now we know 5 is in the correct position, and can scan from position 4
               //situation becomes: 1 2 4 3 [5]    // [] mark list that is DONE :)
               //if number 4 is in position 4, we add it
               //(it is not)
               //now if number 4 is in position 2, swap,
               //(it is not) 
               //now if number 4 is in position 3, swap
               //it IS, swap them and bribes++
               //1 2 3 [4 5]

               //if number 3 is in position 3, we add it
               //1 2 [3 4 5]
               //etc.

               for (int m = MAX_SWAPS; m>0; m--)
               {
                   int left = i-m;
                   if (left>=0 && q[left]==pos)
                   {
                        s = q[left];
                        q[left]= q[left+1];
                        q[left+1]  = s;
                        bribes++;
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                        if (m == 1) //if we didn't find the correct number at the last left position
                                    //after MAX swaps left, we are too chaotic 
                        {
                           System.out.println("Too chaotic"); return;
                        }
                   }
               }
           }
           System.out.println(bribes);


    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

            int[] q = new int[n];

            String[] qItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int qItem = Integer.parseInt(qItems[i]);
                q[i] = qItem;
            }

            minimumBribes(q);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```